# How do I switch images onclick in jQuery or CSS for this accordion?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have a list with dropdowns in them, for each dropdown heading, I have a plus sign image to signify that the list can be dropped when clicked, and once clicked the plus sign would become a minus sign image. Since there is more than one dropdown in the list, i want it to so that when i click on another dropdown, the minus sign on the previous dropdown list will turn back into a plus sign. This accordion was made in CSS. If a solution can be found with either jQuery or CSS, that would be awesome. (I prefer CSS)

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1"  type="radio">
    <label id="change" class="tree" for="ac-1">Dropdown<img class="yellow" src="img/plus.png"></label>
    <article class="ac-small1">
        <hr id="listHr"></hr>
        <p><a href="#">Link<img id="chevRight2" src="img/chevron-right.png"></a></p><hr id="listHr"></hr>
        <p><a href="#">Link<img id="chevRight2" src="img/chevron-right.png"></a></p><hr id="listHr"></hr>
        <p><a href="#">Link<img id="chevRight3" src="img/chevron-right.png"></a></p><hr id="listHr"></hr>
        <p><a href="#">Link<img id="chevRight2" src="img/chevron-right.png"></a></p><hr id="listHr"></hr>
        <p><a href="#">Link<img id="chevRight2" src="img/chevron-right.png"></a></p><hr id="listHr"></hr>
        <p><a href="#">Link<img id="chevRight2" src="img/chevron-right.png"></a></p><hr id="listHr"></hr>
    </article>
</div>
<hr id="listHr"></hr>
<div>
    <input id="ac-2" name="accordion-1" type="radio">
    <label id="change" class="tree" for="ac-2">Dropdown<img class="yellow" src="img/plus.png"></label>
    <article class="ac-small2">
    <hr id="listHr"></hr>
        <p><a href="#">Link<img id="chevRight2" src="img/chevron-right.png"></a></p><hr id="listHr"></hr>
        <p><a href="#">Link<img id="chevRight2" src="img/chevron-right.png"></a></p><hr id="listHr"></hr>
        <p><a href="#">Link<img id="chevRight2" src="img/chevron-right.png"></a></p><hr id="listHr"></hr>
        <p><a href="#">Link<img id="chevRight2" src="img/chevron-right.png"></a></p><hr id="listHr"></hr>
        <p><a href="#">Link<img id="chevRight2" src="img/chevron-right.png"></a></p><hr id="listHr"></hr>
    </article>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#jumma").click(function () {
        if ($(this).children(".yellow").hasClass('minus') ) {
            $(this).chilren(".yellow").attr('src', 'img/plus.png').removeClass('minus');
        } else {
            $(this).children('.yellow').attr('src', 'img/minus.png').addClass('minus');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: DO NOT USE ID!!!! I don't know why i see that a lot on stack overflow, id should be unique, use class instead.  it will break everything, from css to js, nothing will work.

Comment: Using IDs will not "break everything" and is fine to use on unique element selections/bindings. The point wlin is *trying* to make is correct though: this is not an instance for using IDs but instead using a class for multiple element selection and handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have a lot of ids that are the same. Id's should only be used once (for a few reasons). Classes can be used multiple times though.

Secondly, I'm assuming that you want the `<img>` to change when you click the radio buttons. So when you click

```
<input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1"  type="radio">
```

it turns to a minus and when you click

```
<input id="ac-2" name="accordion-1" type="radio">
```

this turns to a minus but all the while only 1 minus is visible and that's on the selected accordion.

If so your JS is pretty much there, however, I would add a class (for this example let's call the class "ac") to the radio buttons and then have the following JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ac").click(function () {
        $('.yellow.').attr('src', 'img/plus.png').removeClass('minus');
        $(this).find('.yellow').attr('src', 'img/minus.png').addClass('minus');
    });
});
```

Also have a look at bootstrap's accordion, it's very good and you can apply the same JS on it if you want.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Hope this helps